# Did Prahlāda attain moksha? Do any scriptures say that he got moksha in the end? Is he dead or alive?

Tags: moksha, prahlada

In the Puranas, Prahlāda is shown as a devotee of Vishnu from a young age itself and Vishnu, in his Narasimha form rescues Prahlāda from his father Hiranyakashipu.

My question is, Did Prahlāda attain moksha? Do any scriptures say that he got moksha in the end? Is he dead or still alive like his grandson Emperor Bali? (he can't have gotten moksha if he is alive)?

Comment: what is moksha to you? Going to Heaven?

Comment: I mean salvation

Comment: I'm pretty sure, although it is not stated explicitly, Prahlada is Sharaba (to avoid the scriptures contradicting themselves). Thus Prahlada/Sharabha is still alive so no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lord Narasimha offers Moksha to Prahlada but Prahlada expresses his concern towards other virtuous people who depend on him. He asks God "how can I leave all these poor people and go to Moksha alone?".
Below is the shloka from Bhagavata saptama skanda Prahlada-kruta Narasimha stotra (9.44)

[image: Bhagavata saptama skanda Prahlada-kruta Narasimha stotra 9.44]

After listening to his stotra God promises that **he would live for one manvantara as king of daityas and then attain Moksha**.

[image: Narasimha's boon 10.11]

This happened in the first manvantara (Swayambhu) so he must have already attained Moksha, but hey wait!

People who have finished their time in this world have to wait for Lord Brahma to take them inside Vaikuntha during Pralaya. Till then they would be living in special places called "Amukta Vaikuntha". I am not able to get exact references for this online, will edit if I get elsewhere.

Dvaita followers believe that Prahlada reincarnated as [Sri Vyasaraja teertha swamiji](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vyasatirtha) and [Sri Raghavendra teertha swamiji](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raghavendra_Tirtha)

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

> [Chapter 5](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-padma-purana/d/doc364212.html), Bhūmi-khaṇḍa, Padma Purāṇa
>
> कमलायाश्चोदरे तु जन्मा स्यानुत्तमं पुनः । प्रह्लादेति च वै नाम
> तस्याख्यानं महात्मनः ॥३१॥
>  बाल्यं भावं गतो विप्राः कृष्णमेव व्यचिंतयत्
> । नरसिंहप्रसादेन देवराजो भवेद्दिवि ॥३२॥
>  देवत्वं लभ्य चैवासावैंद्रं
> पदमनुत्तमम् । मोक्षं यास्यति ज्ञानात्मा वैष्णवं धाम चोत्तमम् ॥३३॥
>
> 31. to 33. He (i.e. Prahlāda) got an excellent birth in the womb of Kamalā
>     (i.e. Prahlāda was born as the son of Kamalā). He was named Prahlāda;
>     the account of that illustrious one (will be narrated by me). O
>     brāhmaṇas, when he was a child, he thought of Kṛṣṇa (i.e. Viṣṇu) only.
>     **Due to the favor of Narasiṃha (i.e. Viṣṇu), he would be the king of
>     gods in heaven. After having obtained godhead, he would also get the
>     position of Indra; he, the all-wise, will attain salvation—Viṣṇu’s
>     abode.**
>
> English Translation by N.A. Deshpande